# How to redirect a "Desktop Desktop"?

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

My website have two versions. Desktop and Mobile version.

When the user access my website via smartphone, I point it to "Mobile version" -> "m.mywebsite.com".

To make it, I'm using the project called [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/)

So far so good.

In "Mobile version" there is a button ("Switch to Desktop Version") that redirect to "Desktop version". The problem is that in "Mobile version", when I clicked in button "Switch to Desktop Version" it get in loop.

For example:

---> Button "Switch to Desktop Version" is clicked;
---> The page is point to "www.mywebsite.com";
---> The page finishes refresh;
---> Since the user is on the smartphone, the script is loaded again and the user is redirected to "m.mywebsite.com";

How I can solve this?

How I can redirect the user to Desktop version in smartphone?

My code:

```
<?php
  require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
  $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <?php if( $detect->isMobile() ) : ?>     
       <script type="text/javascript">
             window.location.href = "http://m.mywebsite.com.br";    
       </script>    
    <?php endif ?>      
 </head>
 <body>    
    <div class="wrapper" style="height: 100vh; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; flex-direction: column">
         <h1>MOBILE VERSION</h1>
         <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com.br">SWITCH TO DESKTOP VERSION</a>
     </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**--------- UPDATE ---------**

Thank's @Uriel, you could solve the problem. Now the page it's working like I want.

```
<?php
  require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
  $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf8">

<?php if( $detect->isMobile() && (!isset($_GET['force_desktop']) || $_GET['force_desktop'] == 'false')) : ?>    
  <?php if( $detect->isMobile() ) : ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         window.location.href = "http://m.mywebsite.com.br";    
    </script>

  <?php endif ?>
<?php endif; ?>

 </head>
 <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0">

 <div class="wrapper" style="height: 100vh; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; flex-direction: column">
   <h1>DESKTOP VERSION</h1>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to store the fact that the desktop version was requested, and NOT redirect if that choice is there. e.g. set a cookie and check for the cookie.

Comment: Don't force people to your mobile site and this becomes a non-issue. As a user, trying to load the normal site and getting redirected because of my user agent is one of the most frustrating things.

Comment: Perhaps when a user redirects, use a session to keep track of the user's preferred client; $_SESSION["prefered-client"] = "MOBILE" or  $_SESSION["prefered-client"] = "DESKTOP". When a page loads, check this session value, and redirect only if it is 1) not set, or 2) they are not on their preferred client. You could also use cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the address of the link

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com.br">SWITCH TO DESKTOP VERSION</a>
```

To the address `http://www.mywebsite.com.br&force_desktop=true`.

---

Then, when checking for mobile, check also that this `GET` variable is `false` (or doesn't exist):

```
if( $detect->isMobile() && (!isset($_GET['force_desktop']) || $_GET['force_desktop'] == 'false'))
```

---

That way, the mobile will load **only** if there is no true `force_desktop` variable, **and** the user uses mobile.

Comment: Solve my problem. Thank's a lot! I updated my question if someone needs.